# What does the "as" statement mean in python?

Tags: python, flask

I'm just starting to learn the Flask framework and was wondering what the 'as' statement does? It's used in conjunction with an 'with' statement.

Here's the example:

```
def init_db():
with closing (connect_db()) as db:
    with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
    db.commit
```

Comment: this is assigned name/label , so that it can be accessed with that name later, same as `db=something`, except it closes the connection when you do `with....as..`

Comment: Here's a [good primer on the with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Comment: As a side note, I'm willing to bet you wanted `db.commit()` on that last line, not `db.commit`.

Comment: As another side note, if you were doing this repeatedly, and you wanted to explicitly `rollback` on failure instead of just `close`-ing, that's a perfect use case for a custom context manager. If that's not already in the PEP or the primer, see [here](http://pastebin.com/vHwCcy7R).

Comment: @hunse: Nice link. But it's funny that that primer implies that writing the generator wrapper is the hard part, rather than wrapping your code in it, especially given that most context managers written in Python are written by writing a generator wrapper with `@contextmanager`…

Answer (score 7):

The `as` keyword is used to add clauses to a few different statements (e.g., [`import`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)); there is no "`as` statement".

In the `with` statement, it means that the value of the `with` context gets assigned to that variable. The precise explanation is in the docs under [The `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), [With Statement Context Managers](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers), and [Context Manager Types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager); [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) gives a more readable explanation (although it's also a little out of date).

---

In simple cases, where an object acts as its own context manager, as a file does, or `decimal.localcontext`, the object gets assigned to the variable. Here, `f` is the file returned by `open('spam')`:

```
with open('spam') as f:
```

In slightly more complex cases, a context manager provides some *other* object that gets assigned to the variable. In the case of `closing(foo)`, the object is the `foo` that it was given in the first place. So here, `g` ends up being the same thing as `f`, even though `closing(f)` is *not* the same thing:

```
f = open('spam')
with closing(f) as g:
```

Some context managers don't provide any object at all. In that case, as you'd expect, `as f` will assign `f` to `None`, and you usually won't have nay good reason to use it. So, the `as` clause is optional. For example, using a `threading.Lock`:

```
with my_lock:
```

---

If you're building context managers from scratch, the way you provide an object (whether `self` or otherwise) to bind to the `as` target is by returning it from the `__enter__` method. Or, if you're building them with the `@contextmanager` decorator around a generator, you do it by `yield`ing the object.